# Angular2 - EXCEPTION: TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I finished building my Angular2/IONIC2 app, the iOS version works fine; however, when I try to run the same page on the Android Simulator an error, I was able to get it when I inspected the running app on CHROME:

```
   EXCEPTION: TypeError: undefined is not a function
  browser_adapter.js:77 EXCEPTION: TypeError: undefined is not a function
  browser_adapter.js:77 STACKTRACE:
  browser_adapter.js:77 TypeError: undefined is not a function
  at new DishesComponent (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:1746:49)
  at AppView._View_MenuPage2.createInternal (MenuPage.template.js:354:31)
  at AppView.create (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:33434:21)
  at TemplateRef_.createEmbeddedView (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:33335:14)
      at ViewContainerRef_.createEmbeddedView (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:33844:35)
      at NgFor._bulkInsert (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:4250:50)
      at NgFor._applyChanges (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:4206:14)
      at NgFor.ngDoCheck (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:4188:22)
      at AppView._View_MenuPage0.detectChangesInternal (MenuPage.template.js:225:42)
      at AppView.detectChanges (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:33581:14)
```

For the records, the issue appears **ONLY** on the android emulator, when I run it on Chrome (MAC), everything is working fine. To emulate I am using **Android 5.1**

*I haven't tried that on a real device, but I guess the result should be the same.*

After some digging, I found the line that causing the issue, but I can't solve it!

I'll share the lines that causing the issue:

**page1.html**

```
<ion-slides id="dishes-content" class="dishes-slides" (ionWillChange)="onCategoryChanged($event.activeIndex)">
 <ion-slide *ngFor="let category of categories; let i = index">

 //When I remove the below line, the issue disappears!!
//This is a directive imported from finalMenu
<dishes [categoryValue]="category" [cart]="cart"></dishes>

   </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

**page1.js**

```
  @Component({
   templateUrl: 'build/pages/page1/page1.html',
   directives: [DishesComponent],
   queries: {
     sliders: new ViewChildren(Slides)
   }
   })
```

**finalmenu.js**

```
  @Component({
  selector: 'dishes',
  inputs: ['categoryValue', 'cart'],
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/finalmenu/finalmenu.html'
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess ViewChildren(Slides) is not defined at this stage...

mike

Comment: If it was not defined then it should not work on iOS nor the chrome browser itself!

Comment: hmm... maybe it's related to the emulator environment and the file:// references...

Comment: Well, it's the emulator that comes with Android Studio, I really can't see where is the issue